# ¿Se puede hacer una cadena de valores en C?

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo a programar, y estoy usando estas 9 variables:

```
srand(time(0));

for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i){
        tiro_local_1 = (rand () % 3);
        tiro_visitante_1 = (rand () % 3);
        tiro_local_2 = (rand () % 3);
        tiro_visitante_2 = (rand () % 3);
        tiro_local_3 = (rand () % 3);
        tiro_visitante_3 = (rand () % 3);
        tiro_local_4 = (rand () % 3);
        tiro_visitante_4 = (rand () % 3);
        tiro_local_5 = (rand () % 3);
    }
```

De tal forma que ese bloque se repita 3 veces. Pero siento que tener todas esas 9 variables no es muy eficiente, y queria saber si hay alguna forma de hacer una cadena de valores en la que solo coloque el "tiro_local" y se vaya "moviendo" por asi decirlo al 2, 3, 4 y 5.

De la misma forma con la otra variable "tiro_visitante".

Y si existe, ¿como es su syntaxis?; y si ocupo alguna libreria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente puedes declarar un [arreglo](https://naps.com.mx/blog/ejemplos-explicados-de-arreglos-en-c/) de `5` elementos, en la cual se llame `tiro_local` y otro arreglo que se denomine `tiro_visitante` (con un tamaño de `4` elementos).

```c
//Esta declaración debe ir antes de usar el arreglo.
int tiro_local[5];
int tiro_visitante[4];
```

Para poder asignarle los valores aleatorios a cada elemento del arreglo, debemos usar un bucle:

```c
for(int j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
   tiro_local[j] = rand() % 3;

for(int j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
   tiro_visitante[j] = rand() % 3;
```

Y por último, para poder repetir el mismo proceso tres veces, lo agregamos en un bucle:

```c
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
      tiro_local[j] = rand() % 3;

    for(int j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      tiro_visitante[j] = rand() % 3;
}
```

Para reutilizar código, podríamos agregar las instrucciones que tiene el bucle principal en una función denominada `tiro`.

```c
void tiro(int* tiro_local, int* tiro_visitante)
{
     //Código del bucle principal
     for(int j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
       tiro_local[j] = rand() % 3;

     for(int j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
       tiro_visitante[j] = rand() % 3;
}
```

Posteriormente, lo invocamos de esta manera:

```c
int tiro_local[5];
int tiro_visitante[4];

for(int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
{
   //Lo que se le envía al parámetro de la función es la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del arreglo.
   tiro(tiro_local, tiro_visitante);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Pero siento que tener todas esas 9 variables no es muy eficiente.

Tu problema no tiene nada que ver con la eficiencia; el programa no va a ser más eficiente por tener más o menos variables. Tu problema es de legibilidad y mantenimiento (cuesta más leer y mantener un código grande que uno pequeño).

---

Cuando el código tiene repeticiones, es un importante indicio para pensar que esa parte repetida se puede [modularizar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularidad_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29) dentro de una función. Veo que tu código consiste en obtener un número aleatorio entre cero y dos para asignarlo a una variable, puedes hacerlo en la siguiente función:

```
void tiro(int *local, int *visitante) {
    if (local)
        *local = (rand () % 3);
    if (visitante)
        *visitante = (rand () % 3);
}
```

De manera que tu bucle podría quedar así:

```
int tiro_local, tiro_visitante;

for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i){
    tiro(&tiro_local, &tiro_visitante); // Primer tiro
    tiro(&tiro_local, &tiro_visitante); // Segundo tiro
    tiro(&tiro_local, &tiro_visitante); // Tercer tiro
    tiro(&tiro_local, &tiro_visitante); // Cuarto tiro
    tiro(&tiro_local, NULL); // Quinto tiro (el visitante no tira)
}
```